# Matlab - Convert Character Vector Into Number Vector?

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I'm trying to implement an oscilloscope for a digital input and send it over a serial port for debugging.  I have the scope software sending Matlab a string like "000000111111111000000001111111000000".  I'd like to plot this.  Is there any way for me to split this string into a vector.  It doesn't seem Matlab allows you to use strsplit() without a delimiter.  I'd rather not bog up the communications with a delimiter between each byte.

Comment: "split this string into a vector" – what exactly do you mean by that? Please edit your question to show what the desired output for your example looks like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With MATLAB's weak typing, this is actually quite easy:

```
>> str = '000000111111111000000001111111000000'
str = 000000111111111000000001111111000000
>> class(str)
ans = char

>> vec = str - '0'
vec =

 Columns 1 through 22:

   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

 Columns 23 through 36:

   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
>> class(vec)
ans = double
```

This subtracts the ordinal value of the character `'0'` from each character in the string, leaving the numerical values `0` or `1`.

Comment: Good Lord I would have never thought that is a logical solution.  I probably have about 100 other lines of code that I could redo now without str2num(). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sscanf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html) with a single value width:

```
a = '000000111111111000000001111111000000'
b = sscanf(a, '%1d');
```

Which returns:

```
>> b.'

ans =

  Columns 1 through 18

     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0

  Columns 19 through 36

     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and fast solution is:

```
data = '000001111111110000000000111111111110000000';
vec = str2double(cellstr(data.').');
```

It will produce a column vector of numeric values. If you want a row vector as output, just use a single transpose:

```
vec = str2double(cellstr(data.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised how difficult this is to do.  But here's what I came up with:

```
str = '000001111111110000000000111111111110000000'; %test string
y = cellfun(@(x) str2num(x), regexp(str,'\d','match'));
plot(y);
```

regexp() seems to be the only way to go.  By default, it return indexes of matches so you need to specify 'match'.  Then you end up with a cell array of strings.  The only good way to convert this into a numerical array is one item at a time with str2num().

I hope this helps someone else out who is assuming there is a straight forward function as I assumed.  And if anyone knows a way to do this without converting my "01...01....01....01....00....00....00....00" stream of bytes into the ascii representations of the binary numbers: "49.....49.....49....49....48....48....48....48", I'd love to hear it.