# Converting a string of chars to an array of numbers according to a dictionary in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have a string containing letters. I want to assing a number to each letter, and convert it to an array. Let's say I have

```
'ABAABCCBA'
```

and I have a dictionary such that `A=1`, `B=2`, `C=3` and thus the array I want is

```
[1,2,1,1,2,3,3,2,1]
```

This is super easy to do in python, but I have to use matlab for some subsequent analysis. Any ideas as to how I can do this without switch case, as succinctly as possible? (Note that this is an MRE and the original string contains 20 different letters)

Comment: `array - 'A' + 1`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121252/matlab-convert-character-vector-into-number-vector

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I mention in my code that this is doable with switch case. I also note that this is trivial in python. It's extremely unfair for you to berate me by saying "SO isn't a free online coding service". I am asking a very simple question, asking for what devices exist in matlab to do what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general method, which doesn't assume that keys or values are consecutive, is as follows:

```
keys = 'ABC';
values = [1 200 30];
data = 'ABAABCCBA';
[~, result] = ismember(data, keys);
result = values(result);
```